# Android builds fail when building with launchctl

Tags: java, android, gradle, launchd

I am trying to write a script to automate my build process and push builds every so often. So ever everything seems to be working except for my JAVA_HOME environment variable.

When building the app normally from command line I specify my JAVA_HOME as:

`/Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

However if I add this as an environment variable to my launchctl.plist I get the following error:

`ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`

This directory does exist and works fine when building the app normally.
If I do not specify the JAVA_HOME then I get the following error on building my app:

`General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60.`

Is there something I am doing wrong or can change to allow launchd to either build without the specified JAVA_HOME or to recognize the JAVA_HOME I am setting?

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/

Comment: @RohitKumar I know how to set JAVA_HOME, and that is what I am setting it to, but when running it from launchctl it says the location is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your environment's path `.zshenv` file in your home directory.

Run `source ~/.zshenv` to update terminal or **Quit** the terminal and reopen it again

Android Studio Dolphin and below:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home`

Android Studio Electric Eel and above:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home`